# Ansible 2.8 not able to resolve dynamic EC2 host using [0] notation

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I am using Ansible Jenkins plugin with Ansible 2.8. The pipeline refers a single playbook 'site.yml' with below contents.

```
---
- hosts: reports[0]
  roles:
    - aaa
    - bbb
    - ccc

- hosts: reports
  roles:
    - ddd
    - ccc
    - eee
```

The host inventory is dynamic to resolve 2 EC2 hosts with reporting_app tag. The host mapping file looks like below

```
[tag_role_reporting_app]

[reports:children]
tag_role_reporting_app
```

I do have ec2.py and ec2.ini files present in the folder.

When the playbook is run by the pipeline, it correctly resolves 2 hosts corresponding to "reports" group. However, it is not able to resolve "reports[0]". As specified in the code, there are some roles which I want to execute only once on one of the two nodes. The remaining set of roles need to be executed on both the nodes.

Pipeline run snippet:

```
playbook: site.yml
19:40:02  
19:40:02    play #1 (reports[0]): reports[0]    TAGS: []
19:40:02      pattern: [u'reports[0]']
19:40:02      hosts (0):
19:40:02        TASK TAGS: []
19:40:02  
19:40:02    play #2 (reports): reports  TAGS: []
19:40:02      pattern: [u'reports']
19:40:02      hosts (2):
19:40:02        10.235.149.163
19:40:02        10.235.148.35
```

What is the correct way to refer one node from the reports group?

Comment: I guess because the hosts are populated by a fact gatherer? You could use [`run_once`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/playbooks_keywords.html#term-62) for those kind of requirement, this way you are sure that your roles are really reusable and do always one act on one host.

Comment: Hi @β.εηοιτ.βε, thanks for your reply. The run_once worked for me. So, I just kept "reports" in the first hosts and added run_once: true. That made it execute the intended roles only on one of the hosts. Thanks again!